# How to modify the internet application for mvc projcect in Visual Studio 2012 code and connect with database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I have been trying to create a web application in ASP.NET MVC 4 by using Visual Studio 2012. I started with internet application and open with default template that has registration, login, home etc pages. I have tried to modify the code available for the registration form as I want and connect with SQL Server database, but it does not work and also only connected with local database it is not connected with my database table I have created in SQL Server. What will I do? Thank you for your help

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with connecting to Database.EF(Entity FrameWork) is preferred.Go through some start up Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your default connection string in your web.config to point your sql server?

The default connection string will be like this

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-yourproj-timestamp;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-yourproj-timestamp.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In your case you should have changed as follows,

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnet-yourproj-timestamp;User Id = xxx;Password = xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I have changed it and connected. unfortunatelly those table avialble by default automatically add to the sql database. also it doesnot save on my database it saves on user  profile                                                         [dbo].[System_Users]
[dbo].[UserProfile]
[dbo].[webpages_Membership]
[dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership]
[dbo].[webpages_Roles]
[dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]